# why state.payload is undefined in reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux

why state is returned empty

i had tried many solutions from this website but non of them worked

```
const initialState = [];
export default function(state = initialState, actions) {
  const { type, payload } = actions;  

  switch (type) {
    case DASHBOARD:
      return [...state,payload]        
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

when this state is mapped to props , payload become undefined.
here when i console log action.payload it is defined but could not be passed in return statement.

Answer (score 0):

May I know for which case it failing?

1. For Dashboard case,it will be "DASHBOARD" until and unless it is not constant.
2. And for your default case,you need to change your initial state like this:

   ```
   const initialState = {payload:"your initial payload",your_other_properties:"here"};
   export default function(state = initialState, actions) {
   const { type, payload } = actions;  

     switch (type) {
       case "DASHBOARD":
         return [...state,payload]        
       default:
         return state;
     }
   }
   ```